# Pass function to a jquery key event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function `foo(peram)` which I want to call from multiple jquery `.keyup()` events.

How can I define/pass function `foo` so that I can call it from inside the event?

I tried something like this:

```
function foo(peram) {
alert(peram);
}

$("#someElement").keyup(function(alert) {
foo("You pressed a key!");
});
```

However I get `TypeError: foo is not a function`.

---

## **Update:**

I have removed everything from my script and html, and it still does not work.

**html:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="../jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body onload="asdf()">
      <input type="text" name="name">
  </body>
</html>
```

**test.js**:

```
function asdf() {

function hqxftg(stuff) {
  alert(stuff);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
$('[name="name"]').keyup(function(hqxftg) {
  alert(typeof hqxftg) 
    hqxftg("asdf");
})
})
}
```

It does seem to work in jsfiddle for some reason.

Comment: the only reason I can think of is the `foo` method is declared in some other scope which is not accessible by the current scope

Comment: did you define your foo method in document ready ?

Comment: I think it works. jsfiddle.net/shyamchandranmec/56WaC/

Comment: @ArunPJohny - If `foo` is not accessible then the error should be `ReferenceError: foo is not defined` instead of `TypeError`. It is more likely that he redefined `foo` somewhere else in his code.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 yes..overlooked that error message.... looks like somebody is overriding the foo reference...

Comment: @ArunPJohny Everything is inside a function called with the `onload` attribute in the `<body>` tag.

Comment: @gandalf3 can you add an `alert(typeof foo)` inside the keyup handler before foo is called

Comment: @gandalf3 - Or you can just do `console.log(foo)` and see what it comes out.

Comment: @ArunPJohny Returns `object`.

Comment: @gandalf3 that is the problem... in your scope `foo` is not a function it is an object

Comment: @ArunPJohny How do I fix it?

Comment: Try to rename your function foo into something else? If foo returns an object it is not your function what it is returning...

Comment: @PazcaldeJonge I have tried `foo`, `test`, and `hqxftg`. Still no luck :/

Comment: check your entire script to see where you are assigning something like `foo = ...`

Comment: @ArunPJohny I removed everything else from my script and html, it's still happening. It doesn't happen in jsfiddle though.

Comment: @ArunPJohny I posted my script and html in the question exactly as tested. There are absolutely no other references to `hqxftg` anywhere.

Comment: @gandalf3 the parameter to the keyup handler is names as `hqxftg` which is the event object - this is overriding the function reference - see my answer beloe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you have named the event parameter same as the function

```
function asdf() {

    function hqxftg(stuff) {
        alert(stuff);
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('[name="name"]').keyup(function (event) {
            alert(typeof hqxftg)
            hqxftg("asdf");
        })
    })
}
```

The event callback `keyup` receives the event object as the first parameter, you are naming it as `hqxftg` which overrides the external scoped function name.

Also there is no need to use the `onload=""`, you can just use the dom ready callback

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    function hqxftg(stuff) {
        alert(stuff);
    }
    $('[name="name"]').keyup(function (event) {
        alert(typeof hqxftg)
        hqxftg("asdf");
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a couple of things...

1) You miss the `;` at the end of calling foo()

2) You are missing tags to close the jQuery selector

When you try this it will work:

```
function foo(peram) {
  alert(peram);
}

$("#someElement").keyup(function(alert) {
  foo("You pressed a key!");
});
```

[JSFiddle here...](http://jsfiddle.net/hCLBj/)

**Update:** Post has been updated and original comment of mine becomes obsolete.
I would go with the comment of Derek.

I am able to reproduce the problem: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rLfHM/)

Is it correct you have also `foo` declared as a var?

Comment: Just a few things: 1. `;` is not necessary in JavaScript. 2. If he was missing a `)` then his code wouldn't even run in the first place.

Comment: I forgot those in the question, but I double checked and they are there in my actual code. I ran the example in my question and it still doesn't work for me.

Comment: I am able to reproduce the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/rLfHM/ (check the console error log). Is it possible that you have also foo declared as a var?

Comment: @PazcaldeJonge Just triple checked, nope. Good idea though.

Comment: @PazcaldeJonge I posted my html and javascript, no variables are declared anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.
HTML

```
<input id="someElement" />
```

Java script:

```
function foo(peram) {
alert(peram);
}
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#someElement").keyup(function() {
       foo("You pressed a key!");
     });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/carunchandran/4RREH/)

Comment: did you checked demo?

Comment: Yes, it works there. I'll update my question with more detail.